# How can I target a specific container and specific computers within my domain?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

How do I get all the children of a specific node in my domain?

```
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 
$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=$strFilter)"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
```

The above code works but gives the entire domain.

If the domain is contoso.com, I am interested in

targeting computers that would be in this container

```
 "LDAP://dc=departmentA,dc=contoso, dc=com"
```

Also if there are very specific computers within departmentA

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `OU=departmentA`.  The LDAP path you gave as an example specifies a domain called **departmenta.contoso.com**, not a container called **departmentA** in the domain **contoso.com**.

Answer (score 1):

Your LDAP uri is wrong if `departmentA` is an organizational unit, it should read `LDAP://OU=departmentA,dc=contoso,dc=com` .

Do yourself a favour and install AD Powershell module(part of RSAT) and your query will then become:

```powershell
Get-ADComputer -Filter $strFilter -SearchBase "ou=departmentA,dc=contoso,dc=com"
```

Answer (score 0):

A "search root" in LDAP terminology is the root node to which the search applies. `New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` with no arguments returns the root node of the current session's logon domain. Since you're providing the root node of the domain as the search root and setting the scope to "subtree", you're searching the entire domain.

If you provide the LDAP path to a specific container as a string argument, it returns a **DirectoryEntry** object representing that container, which you can use as the value of the **SearchRoot** property:

```powershell
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry('LDAP://OU=departmentA,DC=contoso,DC=com')
```

I've found that in some cases if an LDAP path just specifying the DN of the container doesn't work, this format does: `LDAP://<FQDN>/<Container's DN>`, which for this example would be `LDAP://contoso.com/OU=departmentA,DC=contoso,DC=com`. However, I've only encountered this issue when authenticating to a different domain. You shouldn't need to add the FQDN if you're searching your logon domain.